# Pass a file to JUnit test in when()

Tags: java, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to write Unit test case in which I need to pass File created in unit test case class for the use. I've created the file using @Before. But I'm unable to understand how to pass file which I created in the unit test so that obj takes that file for further execution.

```java
public class Core {

    @Bean
    public SomeObject obj(){
       String fileName = "Some file name";
       String r = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileName)); 
    }
}
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class CoreTest extends TestCase {
    File file ;

    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
       file = new File("myFile.txt");
       file.createNewFile();
    }
    @After
    public void cleanUp()
    {
        file.delete();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFunction() {
    Core obj1 = new Core();
        File file = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        FileUtils f = Mockito.mock(FileUtils.class);

        try {
            
            Mockito.when(f.readFileToString(file)).thenReturn(str); //exception thrown here
            SomeObject o = obj1.obj();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertNotNull(obj);
```

This throws

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Comment: Make sure you pass that mock object to that obj method, else FileUtils that use inside that method will act as different variable.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it should be something like this:

```java
try {
    Mockito.doReturn(str).when(f).readFileToString(Mockito.any());
    SomeObject o = obj1.obj();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Because that way you tell Mockito which method call it has to intercept and replace by the desired return value.